# Can you sync CoreData with iCloud?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, microsoft-sync-framework, icloud, data-synchronization

does anyone know if and how you can sync CoreData apps with iCloud? If I understand the Apple iCould instructions right you can not sync CoreData, can you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that you tagged this with Cocoa, I suggest that you watch the [video for WWDC 2011 Session 315](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) - "What's New in Core Data on Mac OS X".  For iOS, check out Session 303 - "What's New in Core Data on iOS".

These will answer all of your questions regarding Core Data and iCloud.  Since this is still under NDA, that's the most I can tell you.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to suggest you start with the new iPhoneCoreDataRecipes for iOS 5.0. You must be a registered developer.

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/126670