# How do i sync core data within iCloud?(OS X Lion App)

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, icloud

As the title tells,i want to sync my core data os x lion app within iCloud,is there any sample code for that?I notice that there is a sample in the WWDC 2011 video session,but i cannot find where to download it,any body can figure it out?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588180/can-you-sync-coredata-with-icloud/8108212#8108212 - the answer you are looking for is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation and watch the devforums.apple.com. There is a sample app in the iOS iCloud topic in the forum you can use as a guideline.